# Where is num's operator == defined in Dart?

Tags: dart

When I run this code in my Android emulator, it prints the following.

```dart
void main() {
  print(1 == 1.0); // true
  print(identical(1, 1.0)); // false
}
```

I also read that the default implementation of `==` is `identical`. That means the operator `==` is overridden, however, when I went to `num` class to see its implementation, it shows the method is abstract.

```dart
bool operator ==(Object other);
```

So, I went to see its implementation in `double` and `int` classes but couldn't find anything there. So, where is that magic happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are implemented at the native level and the Dart declarations are just an interface for these implementations. These implementations can be found at [`sdk/sdk/lib/_internal/`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/master/sdk/lib/_internal) in the Dart sdk repository.

If you want to see the implementation in the VM you can go down to the vm/lib folder and find the double and integer implementations, which include the operators.

I'll use the VM implementation of [integers](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/9b1583101ec9bdb39b66823eb303c6decd973e73/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/integers.dart#L147) as an example which defines the `==` operator and a method it uses:

```dart
@pragma("vm:recognized", "asm-intrinsic")
@pragma("vm:exact-result-type", bool)
@pragma("vm:never-inline")
bool operator ==(Object other) {
  if (other is num) {
    return other._equalToInteger(this);
  }
  return false;
}

@pragma("vm:recognized", "asm-intrinsic")
@pragma("vm:exact-result-type", bool)
bool _equalToInteger(int other) native "Integer_equalToInteger";
```

You can find the same for doubles and possibly something similar for the dart2js compiler. It's possible, however, that the JS compiler doesn't need a special definition because the defined behavior of the `==` operator of `num` seems to be identical to that of JS.